# YQL XML Output with custom namespace

Tags: json, yahoo-pipes, xml-namespaces, yql, dublin-core

I am attempting to parse a JSON feed from Yahoo Pipes to turn it into XML, using YQL. My query is:

"select * from json where url='http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=[pipe-id]&_render=json'"

The problem is that the original Pipe was parsing an RSS feed, filled with dublin core tags (example: dc:title, dc:source, etc). The XML output cannot handle these tags and Yahoo Pipes cannot remove them properly. Whenever I try to run the XML output in any browser, it throws a fit because of the missing  at the beginning of the document.

How can I define a custom namespace from the XML output of YQL?

Comment: Can't you do `select * from xml` with YQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [W3C Online XSLT 2.0 Service](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/) to apply an arbitrary transformation to the XML output. [Here's a sample pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=InW9JFba2xG4CDgzJhOy0Q) that uses this service.